# Append a key value pair at the start of each JSON object in an array using JS

Tags: javascript, json

Essentially I have some data like this:

```
[
 {
  "Forename": "Scott",
  "Surname": "Jones",
  "Age": 18,
 },
 {
  "Forename": "Tina",
  "Surname": "Turner",
  "Age": 20,
 },
 {
  "Forename": "Joe",
  "Surname": "Bloggs",
  "Age": 20,
 }
]
```

I want to know how to add in a key value pair using javascript like so:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "Forename": "Scott",
  "Surname": "Jones",
  "Age": 18,
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "Forename": "Tina",
  "Surname": "Turner",
  "Age": 20,
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "Forename": "Joe",
  "Surname": "Bloggs",
  "Age": 20,
 }
]
```

I was looking at stuff like mapping through the and adding it to each object but that seemed to only let me add a key value pair to the end of each one.

Any help / guidance appreciated!

Comment: _"stuff like mapping"_ may you share that code?

Comment: jsonObj.map(i => i.id = "1");   thats how i was appending to the end of each object

Comment: You need to return the new item, not mutate it. `map(i => ({ id = "1", ...i }) );`

Comment: Notice that while others may propose workarounds, the fields of a JSON object are not intended to have an order (https://www.json.org/json-en.html). "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.". Depending what you do with the object, it will keep the order, put it in alphabetical order, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this I can think of is :

```
let data = [
 {
  "Forename": "Scott",
  "Surname": "Jones",
  "Age": 18,
 },
 {
  "Forename": "Tina",
  "Surname": "Turner",
  "Age": 20,
 },
 {
  "Forename": "Joe",
  "Surname": "Bloggs",
  "Age": 20,
 }
];

data = data.map((e,i) => Object.assign({id: i}, e));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array and want to iterate through it, you can use functional methods like `forEach` or `map`

```js
var id = 0;
const array = [
 {
  "Forename": "Scott",
  "Surname": "Jones",
  "Age": 18,
 },
 {
  "Forename": "Tina",
  "Surname": "Turner",
  "Age": 20,
 },
 {
  "Forename": "Joe",
  "Surname": "Bloggs",
  "Age": 20,
 }
]
array.forEach((elm) => elm.id = id++)
```

Anyway your id property is appended at the end because in javascript the order of the properties of objects is not always guaranteed to be maintained.
[Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0):

The non-numeric keys in a javascript object are ordered by when they are added, so adding a key in a map will place it at the bottom. If you want your key to be positioned higher (it honestly should not matter), you would need to create a new object from your existing one.

We can do that with a function sort of like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "id": 1,
  "Surname": "Jones",
  "Age": 18,
 };

function objectInsertAt(object, position, key, value) {
   let i = 0;
   let result = {};
   
   for (let prop in object) {
       if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
           console.log(prop + ' - ' + i);
           if (position === i) {
               result[key] = value;
           }
           
           result[prop] = object[prop];
       }
       
       i++;
   }
   
   return result;
}

const newObj = objectInsertAt(obj, 2, 'Forename', 'Scott');
console.log(newObj);
```

You can read more about the traversal order of object keys here: https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object

The summary of that article is:

> Property keys are traversed in the following order:
>
> - First, the keys that are integer indices (what these are is explained later), in ascending numeric order.
> - Then, all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
> - Lastly, all symbol keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
>
> Many engines treat integer indices specially (even though they are still strings, at least as far as the ES6 spec is concerned). Therefore, it makes sense to treat them as a separate category of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`

```
    const array = [ { "Forename": "Scott", "Surname": "Jones", "Age": 18, }, { "Forename": "Tina", "Surname": "Turner", "Age": 20, }, { "Forename": "Joe", "Surname": "Bloggs", "Age": 20, } ]
    const updatedArray = array.map((data,id) => ({...data, id}));
```